# Is there a way to make Outlook check the exchange server more frequently for e-mails?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I'm debugging a website and everytime there is an error an e-mail containing details is sent to me. Sometimes I have to click "send/receive" when I expect an e-mail and haven't got it.

Comment: you mean more often than once per minute, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Outlook 2003:
Select Tools > Send/Receive > Send/Receive Settings

[image]

In Outlook 2007:

Select Tools > Options > Mail > Send/Receive

[image]

In Outlook 2010:
File> Options> section Advanced> button Send/Receive…

[image: Outlook 2010]